# Why are sprinkles beneath on donut

Tags: modeling

I need technical support with my donut (Blenderguru tutorial).
My sprinkles suddenly appear on my donut bun? I have managed to make a renderling. But after I opened and closed the program, it looks like this. What happened?? I hope someone can help me?

Comment: Could you please show some images of your scene and/or renderings?

Comment: You will learn more if you watch the video again and again until you notice what you did differently.